# Synaptic Package Manager looking bad under Gnome Shell [Ubuntu 12.04]

Tags: 12.04, gtk, synaptic

This is my first question and I really hope that is has not been answered anywhere, as I could not find it during the search I performed.

I am working under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Gnome Shell (Gnome 3).
I have installed Synaptic Package Manager, which is working great, but the problem is that its looks are awful. It looks like there is a classic theme applied to the synaptic windows only, except for the window title bar. Unfortunately, I cannot post a screenshot yet.

The same issue exists on the Adobe Reader (9.5.1) too, where the popup menu texts are barely visible on high brightness.

Could this happen due to the some missing gtk2 libraries? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please upload screenshot some image hosting websites and give link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on the Adobe aspect, but I've had a similar problem with **Synaptic** on Ubuntu 12.04 when I use a theme from `~/.themes` rather than from `/usr/share/themes`. The reason seems to be that programs that need `sudo` won't follow the theme from `~/.themes`.

Edit: okay, here's [a link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12182997&postcount=2) to some advice I received on how to use a theme from ~/.themes and have programs running via `sudo` look good. Basically, it involves the use of symbolic links from the **user**'s folder to **root**'s folder:

`sudo ln -s ~/.themes /root/.themes`

`sudo ln -s ~/.icons /root/.icons`

Comment: Thank you, that worked for Synaptic! Adobe Reader still looks awful, though. I will have to work around this.

Comment: Worked that around, I had a broken installation of Adobe Reader. I had installed it from the Adobe website. Uninstalled and reinstalled from the Ubuntu partner repo via apt-get. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @errikos, I'm editing my answer to include information on how to use themes from ~/.themes and still have Synaptic look good.

Comment: Thank you very much vasa1! Symbolic links are also a good idea!